# Configure log in aks

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to limit the aks logs for the various containers. Following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-agent-config I created my config map:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
data:
  schema-version:
    #string.used by agent to parse config. supported versions are {v1}. Configs with other schema versions will be rejected by the agent.
    v1
  config-version:
    #string.used by customer to keep track of this config file's version in their source control/repository (max allowed 10 chars, other chars will be truncated)
    ver1
  log-data-collection-settings: |-
    # Log data collection settings
    # Any errors related to config map settings can be found in the KubeMonAgentEvents table in the Log Analytics workspace that the cluster is sending data to.

    [log_collection_settings]
       [log_collection_settings.stdout]
          # In the absense of this configmap, default value for enabled is true
          enabled = false
          # exclude_namespaces setting holds good only if enabled is set to true
          # kube-system,gatekeeper-system log collection are disabled by default in the absence of 'log_collection_settings.stdout' setting. If you want to enable kube-system,gatekeeper-system, remove them from the following setting.
          # If you want to continue to disable kube-system,gatekeeper-system log collection keep the namespaces in the following setting and add any other namespace you want to disable log collection to the array.
          # In the absense of this configmap, default value for exclude_namespaces = ["kube-system","gatekeeper-system"]
          # exclude_namespaces = ["kube-system","gatekeeper-system","kube-node-lease","kube-public","default","nsbpo","nscommon","nsregistry","aks-command"]

       [log_collection_settings.stderr]
          # Default value for enabled is true
          enabled = true
          # exclude_namespaces setting holds good only if enabled is set to true
          # kube-system,gatekeeper-system log collection are disabled by default in the absence of 'log_collection_settings.stderr' setting. If you want to enable kube-system,gatekeeper-system, remove them from the following setting.
          # If you want to continue to disable kube-system,gatekeeper-system log collection keep the namespaces in the following setting and add any other namespace you want to disable log collection to the array.
          # In the absense of this cofigmap, default value for exclude_namespaces = ["kube-system","gatekeeper-system"]
          exclude_namespaces = []

       [log_collection_settings.env_var]
          # In the absense of this configmap, default value for enabled is true
          enabled = false
       [log_collection_settings.enrich_container_logs]
          # In the absense of this configmap, default value for enrich_container_logs is false
          enabled = false
          # When this is enabled (enabled = true), every container log entry (both stdout & stderr) will be enriched with container Name & container Image
       [log_collection_settings.collect_all_kube_events]
          # In the absense of this configmap, default value for collect_all_kube_events is false
          # When the setting is set to false, only the kube events with !normal event type will be collected
          enabled = false
          # When this is enabled (enabled = true), all kube events including normal events will be collected
       #[log_collection_settings.schema]
          # In the absence of this configmap, default value for containerlog_schema_version is "v1"
          # Supported values for this setting are "v1","v2"
          # See documentation at https://aka.ms/ContainerLogv2 for benefits of v2 schema over v1 schema before opting for "v2" schema
          # containerlog_schema_version = "v2"

  metric_collection_settings: |-
    # Metrics collection settings for metrics sent to Log Analytics and MDM
    [metric_collection_settings.collect_kube_system_pv_metrics]
      # In the absense of this configmap, default value for collect_kube_system_pv_metrics is false
      # When the setting is set to false, only the persistent volume metrics outside the kube-system namespace will be collected
      enabled = false
      # When this is enabled (enabled = true), persistent volume metrics including those in the kube-system namespace will be collected

  alertable-metrics-configuration-settings: |-
    # Alertable metrics configuration settings for container resource utilization
    [alertable_metrics_configuration_settings.container_resource_utilization_thresholds]
        # The threshold(Type Float) will be rounded off to 2 decimal points
        # Threshold for container cpu, metric will be sent only when cpu utilization exceeds or becomes equal to the following percentage
        container_cpu_threshold_percentage = 95.0
        # Threshold for container memoryRss, metric will be sent only when memory rss exceeds or becomes equal to the following percentage
        container_memory_rss_threshold_percentage = 95.0
        # Threshold for container memoryWorkingSet, metric will be sent only when memory working set exceeds or becomes equal to the following percentage
        container_memory_working_set_threshold_percentage = 95.0

    # Alertable metrics configuration settings for persistent volume utilization
    [alertable_metrics_configuration_settings.pv_utilization_thresholds]
        # Threshold for persistent volume usage bytes, metric will be sent only when persistent volume utilization exceeds or becomes equal to the following percentage
        pv_usage_threshold_percentage = 60.0

    # Alertable metrics configuration settings for completed jobs count
    [alertable_metrics_configuration_settings.job_completion_threshold]
        # Threshold for completed job count , metric will be sent only for those jobs which were completed earlier than the following threshold
        job_completion_threshold_time_minutes = 360
  integrations: |-
    [integrations.azure_network_policy_manager]
        collect_basic_metrics = false
        collect_advanced_metrics = false
    [integrations.azure_subnet_ip_usage]
        enabled = false

# Doc - https://github.com/microsoft/Docker-Provider/blob/ci_prod/Documentation/AgentSettings/ReadMe.md
  agent-settings: |-
    # prometheus scrape fluent bit settings for high scale
    # buffer size should be greater than or equal to chunk size else we set it to chunk size.
    #[agent_settings.prometheus_fbit_settings]
    #  tcp_listener_chunk_size = 10
    #  tcp_listener_buffer_size = 10
    #  tcp_listener_mem_buf_limit = 200

    # The following settings are "undocumented", we don't recommend uncommenting them unless directed by Microsoft.
    # They increase the maximum stdout/stderr log collection rate but will also cause higher cpu/memory usage.
    ## Ref for more details about Ignore_Older -  https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.7/pipeline/inputs/tail
    # [agent_settings.fbit_config]
    #   log_flush_interval_secs = "1"                 # default value is 15
    #   tail_mem_buf_limit_megabytes = "10"           # default value is 10
    #   tail_buf_chunksize_megabytes = "1"            # default value is 32kb (comment out this line for default)
    #   tail_buf_maxsize_megabytes = "1"              # defautl value is 32kb (comment out this line for default)
    #   tail_ignore_older = "5m"                      # default value same as fluent-bit default i.e.0m

metadata:
  name: container-azm-ms-agentconfig
  namespace: kube-system
```

Reading the agent logs I find a couple of weird things, in the figure below it says that the config map has been changed, but I also find that both stderr and stdout have an exclusion, what I am wondering is, since stdout is disabled as is this possible? which means **config :: No ADX database name set, using default value: containerinsights**, I tried to search but can't find any information.

[image]

Also in the Log Analytics workspace I see that the stdout logs are still retrieved in the
ContainerLog resource.

I wonder if I have not misinterpreted the guide or if I have misconfigured

Comment: config :: No ADX database name set, using default value: containerinsights
this is not the error here we didn't create any ADX database so containerinsights will take the default value
please refer this link for STDOUT/STTRR
https://www.danielstechblog.io/tweaking-data-collection-for-azure-monitor-for-containers/#:~:text=Both%20stdout%20%26%20stderr%20log%20collection%20are%20turned,for%20containers%20and%20stored%20in%20Azure%20Log%20Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tired to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the expected results***

***I have created and deployed the config file***

```
Vi container-azm-ms-agentconfig.yaml
kubectl apply -f container-azm-ms-agentconfig.yaml
```

***We can check the logs using below command***

```
  kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

[image]

***We can check the logs using below command***

```
kubectl logs pod_name -n kubesystem
```

[image]

When I check the logs got the same like ***config :: No ADX database name set, using default value: containerinsights***

***This is not the error, here we didn't create any ADX database so containerinsights will take the default value
if we need we can create the ADX sample data base then it won't show the message
[you can refer this link](https://www.danielstechblog.io/tweaking-data-collection-for-azure-monitor-for-containers/#:%7E:text=Both%20stdout%20&%20stderr%20log%20collection%20are%20turned,for%20containers%20and%20stored%20in%20Azure%20Log%20Analytics)***